# How to view external go module dependencies in vscode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, dependency-management

Sometimes I really need to browse and check the code from external dependencies add to my go module.

Although I could `CMD+click` on the method and vscode editor opens the go file from external dependency, I would really like to see and quickly check other files from the package.

Goland allows this by showing module dependencies.

Is there any way to enable displaying module dependencies in visual studio code?

Comment: I just follow any of "Go to definition" links that point to the source code inside the module cache.

Comment: @Hana right, but this only opens a single file. What I want is to look into the package and check the code from related files. Just like how GoLand navigates to the module source and allows exploring all the files and packages

Comment: @Vivek we still can't do that in vscode. This is the only reason I'm using Goland !

Comment: I want this feature

Answer (score 3):

There is no such feature in the oficial [Go extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=golang.Go), or any extension that provides that as well.

However, there is an open issue https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/issues/2156 in the Go extension. It does not have too many votes (IMO), but it is assigned to a milestone that holds ideas that at least, are on the table to discussion.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this way is as quickly as you want, but after you `cmd+Click` and reached the external file you can do either of

1. Navigate all the file through navbar, this way you can check what version of the dependency and you can choose between different version that is available on your module directorey [image]

2. Or you can Copy Path `[Ctrl+K Ctrl+Alt+C on linux]` then open terminal and do `code <file-directory>`. It opens a new vscode window on that directory so you can check all the files of the external dependencies.

I know it seems like a lot of step but once you get used to vscode shortcut(copy path, open terminal) i think it's the best we have right now :)